# What are the ways and how can I receive the transaction details that automatically occur every month through PayPal subscriptions?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have created a React application where users can subscribe to a subscription and can also cancel the subscription, but I am wondering what are the ways and how can I receive the transaction details that automatically occur every month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/)

The event names for Subscriptions are listed here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions

---

Another way, of course, is to log into [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) and go to Activity -> Reports and do an Activity Download, which can be in csv format

Comment: Thanks I noticed that there is a PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED web hook in the link you provided but this does not have a related method, do you have an idea to how to implement this webhook?

Comment: The first overview and configuration link discusses implementation.

Comment: Ok cool, do you happen to know which webhook event is specifically for when a user is charged every month/subscription charge? I tested out PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED and in the response data it doesnt specify the users name, email, address, etc.. which is what I want to record in my DB.

Comment: Record that information when the subscription is created. PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED is for when there is a charge.